# How to solve $x'=x^2$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need this in order to solve a PDE.

How does one solve $X'(s)=X(s)^2?$

where $X(0)=x_0$.

Does it involve cosines/sin? I tried use to $e$, but I don't think it works.

Comment: What is $X'$, $s$ and $x$?

Comment: $s$ is $\in \mathbb{R}$ used to parameterize $X$. Oh it should be $X^2$. So for instance, if $X'(s) = X$, then $X(s) = e^s$.

Comment: @KangHoonYou I've made it $X(s)^2$ for further clarification. Feel free to revert if you like.

Comment: But I still do not see, what makes it a *partial* differential equation? It looks like an ordinary differential equation that can be solved by separation of variables?

Answer (score 2):

if $x_0 = 0,$  then $x = 0$ is the solution. for $x_0 \neq 0, $ you can separate the differential equation to give you $$\frac{dx}{x^2} = ds.$$
integrating this gives you $$\int_0^s ds = \int_{x_0}^x \frac{dx}{x^2} \to \frac1x - \frac1{x_0} = s $$ this can be simplified to $$x = \frac{x_0}{1-sx_0} $$

Answer (score 1):

What about $X(s)=-\frac{1}{s}$ the general solution being $X(s)=-\frac{1}{s+C}$ where $C$ is a constant. But if I guess $s$ is arc length the constant is irrelevant

Comment: This doesn't quite work, because the constant doesn't show up in the derivative.

Comment: The constant is indeed stupid

Comment: It's right now, +1

Comment: This solution is only for the special case $C =0$.  See Zubin Mukrrjee's answer.

Comment: And note that we cannot have $C = 0$ for the given initial condition $X(0) = x_0$.  We need $C \ne 0$ to keep $X(0)$ *finite*.

Answer (score 1):

One family of solutions, for any constant $C$, is $$X(s)=-\frac{1}{s + C}$$

It gives the derivative as

$$X'(s) = \frac{1}{(s+C)^2}$$